# Weird formatting for Item lookup

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, lookup-column

I have a `lookup` column  in a `List` (A) which gets its value from a `Single line of text` in another `List` (B) where there is only a `Title` column. When sending out emails and I try to look up the value of the column in A which is retrieved from B, the formatting is weird.

Is it because the columns in A and B are linked, therefore leading to odd formats?

Lookup format in the email - **[%Current Item:Application%]**

Result in the email - **1;#Application**

Suppose to be just **Application**

These are my options for `Return field as:` and they both return the same error.

- As String
- Lookup Value (as Text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the option for "Return field as" to `Lookup Value`, while selecting `[%Current Item:Application%]`

For reference, have a look at screenshot below.Instead of "As String", select `Lookup Values,Comma Delimited`

[image]